# tfs How to Get Area Path (as string) from Area Id value

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When i save workItem for the first time, I'm using TeamFoundationRequestContext to see values of some fields and do some validation. 
Also i need to check AreaPath, but in RequestContext there is only areaId comes. So, maybe there is a TFS API to get AreaPath as string using Area ID. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the Area Path by creating a query like:
[image]

Then select Area Path from query result.

Or you can query Area Path field for a work item with API:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("URL"));
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
            WorkItemStore workitemstore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

            var wr = workitemstore.GetWorkItem(ID);
            foreach(Field f in wr.Fields)
            {
                if (f.Name == "Area Path")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(f.Value);
                }
            }
```

Comment: When the WorkItem firstTime saves, where is no workItem Id in context

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any easy way to get Area Path via Area ID.

The method you may use is query the Area Path via Area ID from SQL Database, however accessing to TFS SQL Database directly is not recommended.

And if you are using TFS2015, you can also use [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes) to get the node information. The information include the Area ID, you can then search the Area ID in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to enumerate areas using the API:

- This [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/07/10/tfs-2010-sdk-get-projects-iterations-area-path-queries-and.aspx) describes accessing the areas using `Project.AreaRootNodes` (section 4).
- This [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/30/tfs-api-part-9-get-areaiteration-programmatically/) describes enumerating the areas using the underlying XML structure.

The first approach returns a [Node](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.node(v=vs.120).aspx) object that has both an `Id` property as a `Path` property, so you can map these.